# Http\Request and Facades\Request conflict

Tags: laravel

How to use `Http\Request` and `Facades\Request` together same time.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

In my custom login, I have used `Laravel-Throttle` not to attempt login too many times. The problem is when not using `Http\Request` error shows

> FatalThrowableError Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

and if using `Facades\Request`, following error occurs

> ErrorException Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::instance() should not be called statically"

Here is my code block,

[image]

I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: Please add code instead of image

Answer (score 3):

You can alias one of conflicting namespace and use it

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request as HttpRequet; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Then when you need to use Request within the `Illuminate\Http` namespace you can simply use `HttpRequest`

Or if you can inline the namespace

Answer (score 0):

Call the class directly to avoid namespace issues: `\Illuminate\Http\Request::instance();`